# MUI and Tailwind: Use same color palette

Tags: material-ui, tailwind-css, color-palette

Is there a good approach when I use MUI (Material UI) with Tailwind css to use the same color palette in my code?
(For example MUI theme should use the colors which I define in my tailwind.config)

Currently I have an extra file colors.js and define my hex-colors with const. And then use this variables in both. But I don't really like this solution :/

color.js

```
type module.exports = {
primaryLightColor: '#757ce8',
primaryMainColor: '#224AA6',
primaryDarkColor: '#042757',

secondaryLightColor: '#BDC1C9',
secondaryMainColor: '#8B969D',
secondaryDarkColor: '#4C5356',

errorColor: '#F44336',

warningColor: '#FF9800',

infoColor: '#A5C8FF',

successColor: '#82C64D',

backgroundColor: '#F7F8FA',
};
```

theme.tsx

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';
import {
  primaryLightColor,
  primaryMainColor,
  primaryDarkColor,
  secondaryLightColor,
  secondaryMainColor,
  secondaryDarkColor,
} from './colors';

export const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: primaryLightColor,
      main: primaryMainColor,
      dark: primaryDarkColor,
    },
    secondary: {
      light: secondaryLightColor,
      main: secondaryMainColor,
      dark: secondaryDarkColor,
    },
 
  },
});
```

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const {
  primaryLightColor,
  primaryMainColor,
  primaryDarkColor,
  secondaryLightColor,
  secondaryMainColor,
  secondaryDarkColor,
  errorColor,
  warningColor,
  infoColor,
  successColor,
  backgroundColor,
} = require('./app/styles/colors.js');

module.exports = {
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
  content: ['./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  important: '#root',
  theme: {
    colors: {
      primary: {
        light: primaryLightColor,
        main: primaryMainColor,
        dark: primaryDarkColor,
      },
      secondary: {
        light: secondaryLightColor,
        main: secondaryMainColor,
        dark: secondaryDarkColor,
      },
      error: errorColor,
      warning: warningColor,
      info: infoColor,
      success: successColor,
      background: backgroundColor,
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```